# Arabic text not storing in the mysql data base?

Tags: php, mysql

i have an mysql table member. 
member name has arabic names. mname collation set as `utf8_general_ci`.

when user enters arabic name its stores in the db table as some other characters. but when i retrieve and display it in the site, it displays correctly as Arabic text. why its not storing as arabic text in the database table ?

i tried this but only i am getting question marks no Arabic text...

```
1- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

2- MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci

3- your database and table collations are set to: utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci

Then, add this code in your php script when you connect to db:

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

**Php Code:**

using simple php.

```
$mname = $_POST['mname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$country = $_POST['country'];



$query="insert into member (mname, email, password, gender, age, city, country) values ('$mname','$email','$password', '$gender', '$age','$city','$country')";
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Maybe the tool in which you see those "other characters" uses a wrong encoding?

Comment: `...its stores in the db table as some other characters...` how do you know that? Are you using something like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: How are you checking the contents of the table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @AxelAmthor yes. using phpmyadmin.

Comment: if your application stores / shows arabic chars properly and phpMyadmin will not, you have a problem with your phpMyAdmin settings, but obviously neither with your DB nor your Application.

Comment: @Axel Nope, it typically points to a misconfigured database connection encoding from the inserting/reading PHP script, not phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @deceze: yep, probably. If phpMyAdmin is not showing UTF8 properly, I would start from there before fiddling around in my own PHP code anyway.

Comment: @user2490465: what if you edit / store / retrieve arabic chars directly in phpMyAdmin? Are they properly treated then?

Comment: @Axel No, again: phpMyAdmin is *probably* fine, it's *probably* showing what's actually stored in the database. The problem is typically (90%+ in my experience) that the data was inserted incorrectly. Read my above-linked article.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that could be problem with that to set meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

also you have to set column collection type it should be same `utf8_general_ci.` more over table  and database type will also consider as same.

And also some point to be carefull like

o read ,write and sort Arabic text in mysql database using php correctly, make sure that:

1- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

2- MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci

3- your database and table collations are set to: utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci

Then, add this code in your php script when you connect to db:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

for more details: [LINK](http://www.adviesenzo.nl/examples/php_mysql_charset_fix/)

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: where should i set these (1)- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

(2)- MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci  ???

Comment: you can set with php as well as mysql also, you can find syntax for same.

Comment: @liyakat i dont get it. in 'member'table 'mname' collation set as utf8_general_ci. it shows mname correctly in the webpage. that shows the arabic characters. but the problem is in the phpmyadmin table the 'mname' field is not showing arabic charactersits showing some other chars.. i used only this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>. now tell me what should i do???

Comment: what do you mean by `some other chars`? Probably it's hex?

Comment: @AxelAmthor i have seen these chars... Ø´Ø³Ø¨, Ù„Ø§Ø´Ø³, Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù„ Ø¨Ø§Ø³Ù„

Comment: please go throw all steps again :(

Comment: @liyakat i used these mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); now i it showing only ???? question marks in the mname field....

Comment: is fields encoding to utf8_general_ci  ?

Comment: now, i saw only ???? question marks .. no Arabic characters. in the webpage also i see only question marks...